# Insert String in a CSV file matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

how do I insert a string into a csv file in matlab. i used this code to write some data and create my csv file:
[image: Create and Write data into a csv file]

and here is the output of the code:
[image: Output of the code]

I'm trying to insert some text in the first 2 columns before the numerical data..

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches are possible here.
Let's take a look at some of them:

1. If you need to add string to your csv file.
   For example, I create some csv file like your:

   ```
   q = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];
   csvwrite('csvlist4.csv',q,2,0);
   ```

   All troubles is to add some string to csv - it's because we need to combine numeric and text data. There are no good functions for it in Matlab except low levels:

   ```
   c = 'some big text';
   fid = fopen('csvlist4.csv','r+');
   fprintf(fid,c);
   ```

   How it works: the data in csv is an array. I put data in 3rd row, so first and second is an empty but they have ','. When you use `fprintf` it will replace this `,` with your text. So if text is too long it will overwrite your data. 
   How to avoid this?
2. Easiest way - is to do it with help of `xlswrite` function. For your example:

   ```
   txt = cell(size(Q))
   txt{1} = 'this is your text'
   X = [txt; num2cell(Q)]
   xlswrite('new.xlsx',X)
   ```

   Result:

[image]

Important moment here: number of cell for text must be the same as your data. But I filled with the text only first cell in my example.

3. And the one more way: read csv file, modify it's data and write to csv:

   ```
   csvwrite('csvlist4.csv',a,2,0);
   m = csvread('csvlist4.csv');
   fid = fopen('csvlist4.csv','w');
   c = 'your text'
   fprintf(fid, c); fprintf(fid, '\n');
   fclose(fid);
   dlmwrite('csvlist4.csv', m(3:end,:), '-append');
   ```

Of course you can use cell array instead `c` and so on and so on.
Hope it helps!

Comment: can you pls explain this part? "dlmwrite('csvlist4.csv', m(3:end,:), '-append');" i'm trying to add a string in a specific cell. sorry, i'm just new to matlab so i'm still figuring things out. Thanks :)

Comment: @Zurc, sorry for the late answer - I was at vacation :) 
`dlmwrite` is function for writing files. It allows to ADD data to file (not to rewrite!). For this we use `'-append'` keyword. but we need to add new data: first strings of `m` is an old data (we read it from csv), so lets add other strings only - `m(3:end,:)` - this mean we take strings from 3 to end and all columns. Hope it's clearer now :)